# How to integrate windows authentication (SSO) in my custom web server Java based?

Tags: java, webserver, single-sign-on, kerberos, jaas

I have a custom web server application Java based and I need to support Single-Sign-On.
I made a research on the issue and found out that I can use JAAS to implement SSO. I already configured my http server to accept the Authentication handshake process, so I have the logged-in user Authentication encoded in my java application and I am passing it my JAAS authentication function.
Now, I need to authenticate the user with my domain controller. So, I'm using jaas.conf file to define the LoginModule:

```
SSOAUTH {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required  
  useKeyTab=false
  storeKey=true
  useTicketCache=false
  debug=true;
};
```

As you can see I would like to use the Kerberos protocol.
 The first question is: Do I need to make some installation/configuration for my domain controller to support this protocol?

This is my java code in my web server application that will handle the whole authentication process using JAAS:

```
public class LDAPClient
{
   private static final String LOGIN_MODULE_NAME = "SSOAUTH";


/**
 * Constructor
 * @param domain
 * @param ldapServer
 * @param jaasConfigPath
 */
public LDAPClient(String domain, String ldapServer, String jaasConfigPath)
{
    System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", domain);
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", ldapServer); // LDAP active directory server name
    System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "true");
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", jaasConfigPath); // path to the jaas.conf file.
}


/**
 * Authenticates the given kerberos token and returns the client principal.
 *
 * @param argKerberosTokenAsBase64 The kerberos content token.
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public String authenticate(String argKerberosTokenAsBase64) throws Exception
{
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte[] kerberosToken = decoder.decodeBuffer(argKerberosTokenAsBase64.substring("Negotiate ".length()));
    String clientName;

    try
    {
        // Login to the KDC and obtain subject for the service principal
        Subject subject = createServiceSubject(argKerberosTokenAsBase64);
        if (subject != null)
        {
            clientName = acceptSecurityContext(subject, kerberosToken).toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("Security context successfully initialized!");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to obtain kerberos service context");
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        System.out.println("Token: " + argKerberosTokenAsBase64);
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(throwable);
    }

    return clientName;
}

/**
 * Creates service subject based on the service principal and service
 * password.
 *
 * @param password
 * @return
 * @throws LoginException
 */
private static Subject createServiceSubject(String password)
        throws LoginException
{
    // "Client" references the JAAS configuration in the jaas.conf file.
    LoginContext loginCtx = new LoginContext(LOGIN_MODULE_NAME, new LoginCallbackHandler(password));
    loginCtx.login();
    return loginCtx.getSubject();
}

/**
 * Completes the security context initialisation and returns the client
 * name.
 * @param argSubject
 * @param serviceTicket
 * @return
 * @throws GSSException
 */
private static String acceptSecurityContext(Subject argSubject, final byte[] serviceTicket) throws GSSException
{
    // Accept the context and return the client principal name.
    return (String) Subject.doAs(argSubject, new PrivilegedAction()
    {
        public Object run()
        {
            try
            {
                // Identify the server that communications are being made
                // to.
                GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
                GSSContext context = manager.createContext((GSSCredential) null);
                context.acceptSecContext(serviceTicket, 0, serviceTicket.length);
                return context.getSrcName().toString();
            }
            catch (GSSException exp)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(exp);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

I am having the following LoginException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Pre-authentication information was invalid (24)

I am passing the kerberos authentication token to the LoginContext, see the call to createServiceSubject(), in order to get the Subject, is it correct or I missing something here?

And this is parts from the System.out debug error:

```
>>>KRBError:
 sTime is Wed Feb 12 14:29:17 IST 2014 1392208157000
 suSec is 301542
 error code is 25
 error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
 realm is DOMAIN.LOCAL
 sname is krbtgt/DOMAIN.LOCAL
 eData provided.
 msgType is 30
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 19
 PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23
 PA-ETYPE-INFO2 salt = null
 salt for 3 is DOMAIN.LOCALskadar
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 2
 PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 16
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 15
AcquireTGT: PREAUTH FAILED/REQUIRED, re-send AS-REQ
Updated salt from pre-auth = DOMAIN.LOCALskadar
>>>KrbAsReq salt is DOMAIN.LOCALskadar
Pre-Authenticaton: find key for etype = 3
AS-REQ: Add PA_ENC_TIMESTAMP now
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.DesCbcMd5EType
```

Comment: You might want to look at SPNEGO. There is a java implementation at http://spnego.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I did look into that, but I don't know if I can use it with my custom http server, because I know it can works with well known servers like Tomcat, etc.

Comment: One more thing that I forgot to mention is that I need to support cross platform SSO (windows, linux, ...)

Comment: the password entered is incorrect. Create a new user in AD and retry. btw how are you passing principal to JAAS? It could be you are not passing any principal at all to jaas. Is JAAS prompting for it.

Comment: Ok, thanks Arunav. I'll check that, you might be right about the principal...

Answer (score 0):

Use [SPNEGO/Kerberos Authenticator and Active Directory Realm for Apache Tomcat 6](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/) if you are on Tomcat.